How do multi user applications use databases?
For services that have multiple users, how does that translate at the database layer?  Take a simple key-value store that would use a three column table: ID (acting as a primary key, I know that's a thing), key, value.
If you now support multiple users, would you:

have the same schema and a per-user table;
add an owner column to my table above;
something else entirely.

My intuition leans to solution (2), and all queries would restrict with owner = "foo".  But as I said, I barely have any intuition.  If you do go with (2), would the ID still be an ever-increasing integer, or would (owner, ID) be a sort of composite primary key?

The proper term for the concept you are referring to is "tenant", not "user". The term "user" has so many other uses that it is practically unusable.  (See what I did there?)
So, the question is "how do you implement multi-tenancy in databases?"
And the answer of course, is with a "tenant_id" field. Always.
From a relational point of view, any solution that involves a table-per-something is wrong.  No matter what that something is.
